# How to loop through a list to create a specific other list

Tags: prolog

I need to define a predicate that parses a given list that looks like the following:

```
change([10,-,6], List). //send it this
List = [item(num, 10), item(minus, _), item(num, 6)] //returns exactly this.
```

I have no idea how to check if some item in the list is a 'num', or if its a minus or what...

```
change([], _).
change([H|Rest], List) :- "Do something with atom here?" , transform(Rest, [item(Atom, H) | List] ).
```

What might something like this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're applying a transformation on each list' element, your change/2 should be

```
change([], []). 
change([H|Rest], [Q|List]) :- qualify(H,Q) change(Rest, List]).
```

and

```
qualify(N, item(num, N)) :- number(N), !.
qualify(-, item(minus, _)) :- !.
qualify(A, item(atom, A)).  % you left unspecified, assume everything else is an atom...
```

the change/2 it's really a maplist, and could be written as:

```
change(I, O) :- maplist(qualify, I, O).
```

Comment: I think that works but I am not sure why. It does not look like H and Q are never added to any list, where does that happen?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to explain: in Prolog we don't 'add to a list', but we declare the patterns that make a predicate appropriate. Then the rule with [H|Rest] will be selected only when 'called' with first argument *can* bind to a list. The same for [Q|List]. Given a list, 'adding or taking the head' are consequences of pattern matching...